# Validation of checkbox in Shopware 6 only working upon up and down scroll

Tags: twig-extension, shopware6

I moved the terms and conditions consent from the original twig template so that it shows at a different position on the website. My problem is that when the consent checkbox is not checked, a warning should be shown to the user when clicking the payment button. This however only happens, when scrolling up and down on the website after clicking the finish payment button. Does anyone see my mistake?

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/index.html.twig' %}

{% block base_header %}
    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/header/header-minimal.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block base_navigation %}{% endblock %}

{% block page_checkout_main_content %}
    {% block page_checkout_confirm %}
        {% block page_checkout_confirm_header %}
            <h1 class="confirm-main-header">
                {{ "checkout.confirmHeader"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
            </h1>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block page_checkout_confirm_alerts %}
            {% block page_checkout_confirm_violations %}
                {% for violation in formViolations.getViolations() %}
                    {% set snippetName = "error.#{violation.code}" %}
                    {% set fieldName = violation.propertyPath|trim('/', 'left') %}

                    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/utilities/alert.html.twig' with {
                        type: "danger",
                        content: snippetName|trans({'%field%': fieldName})|sw_sanitize
                    } %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endblock %}
        {% endblock %}
        
        {% block page_checkout_confirm_address %}
            <div class="confirm-address">
                {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-address.html.twig' %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block page_checkout_confirm_payment_shipping %}
            <div class="confirm-payment-shipping">
                <div class="row">
                    {% block page_checkout_confirm_payment %}
                        <div class="col-sm-6 confirm-payment">
                            {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-payment.html.twig' %}
                        </div>
                    {% endblock %}

                    {% block page_checkout_confirm_shipping %}
                        <div class="col-sm-6 confirm-shipping">
                            {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-shipping.html.twig' %}
                        </div>
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block page_checkout_confirm_product_table %}
            <div class="confirm-product">
                {% block page_checkout_confirm_table_container %}
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% block page_checkout_confirm_table_header %}
                                {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-product-header.html.twig' %}
                            {% endblock %}

                            {% block page_checkout_confirm_table_items %}
                                {% for lineItem in page.cart.lineItems %}
                                    {% block page_checkout_confirm_table_item %}
                                        {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-item.html.twig' %}
                                    {% endblock %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
        
        {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos %}
            <div class="confirm-tos">
                <div class="card checkout-card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_header %}
                            <div class="card-title">
                                {{ "checkout.confirmTermsHeader"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_revocation_notice %}
                            {% if config('confirm.revocationNotice') %}
                                <p class="revocation-notice">
                                    {% block page_checkout_confirm_revocation_notice_link %}
                                        <a href="{{ path('frontend.cms.page',{ id: config('core.basicInformation.revocationPage') }) }}"
                                           {{ dataBsToggleAttr }}="modal"
                                           title="{{ "checkout.confirmRevocationNotice"|trans|striptags }}"
                                           data-url="{{ path('frontend.cms.page',{ id: config('core.basicInformation.revocationPage') }) }}">
                                            {{ "checkout.confirmRevocationNotice"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                                        </a>
                                    {% endblock %}
                                </p>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control %}
                            <div class="{{ formCheckboxWrapperClass }}">
                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_checkbox %}
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                           class="checkout-confirm-tos-checkbox {{ formCheckInputClass }}{% if formViolations.getViolations('/tos') is not empty %} is-invalid{% endif %}"
                                           required="required"
                                           id="tos"
                                           form="confirmOrderForm"
                                           name="tos"/>
                                {% endblock %}

                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_label %}
                                    <label for="tos"
                                           class="checkout-confirm-tos-label custom-control-label">
                                        {{ "checkout.confirmTerms"|trans({
                                            '%url%': path('frontend.cms.page',{ id: config('core.basicInformation.tosPage') })
                                        })|raw }}
                                    </label>
                                {% endblock %}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block page_checkout_confirm_hidden_line_items_information %}
            {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/checkout/hidden-line-items-information.html.twig' with {
                cart: page.cart,
                lineItems: page.cart.lineItems
            } %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block page_checkout_additional %}
    {% if config('core.cart.showCustomerComment') %}
        <div class="checkout-additional">
            {% block page_checkout_finish_customer_comment %}
                <div class="card checkout-card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_customer_comment_header %}
                            <div class="card-title">
                                {{ "checkout.customerCommentHeader"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_customer_comment_control %}
                            <div class="checkout-customer-comment-control">
                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_customer_comment_control_textfield_label %}
                                    <label class="form-label" for="{{ constant('Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Order\\SalesChannel\\OrderService::CUSTOMER_COMMENT_KEY') }}">
                                        {{ "checkout.customerCommentLabel"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                                    </label>
                                {% endblock %}

                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_customer_comment_control_textfield %}
                                    <textarea class="form-control"
                                              placeholder="{{ "checkout.customerCommentPlaceholder"|trans|sw_sanitize }}"
                                              id="{{ constant('Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Order\\SalesChannel\\OrderService::CUSTOMER_COMMENT_KEY') }}"
                                              form="confirmOrderForm"
                                              name="{{ constant('Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Order\\SalesChannel\\OrderService::CUSTOMER_COMMENT_KEY') }}"></textarea>
                                {% endblock %}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% set formAddHistoryOptions = {
    entries: [{
        state: {},
        title: 'account.ordersTitle'|trans,
        url: path('frontend.account.order.page')
    }]
} %}

{% block page_checkout_aside_actions %}
    <div class="checkout-aside-action">
        <form id="confirmOrderForm"
              action="{{ path('frontend.checkout.finish.order') }}"
              data-form-csrf-handler="true"
              data-form-preserver="true"
              data-form-submit-loader="true"
              data-form-add-history="true"
              data-form-add-history-options='{{ formAddHistoryOptions|json_encode }}'
              method="post">

            {% block page_checkout_aside_actions_csrf %}
                {{ sw_csrf('frontend.checkout.finish.order') }}
            {% endblock %}

            {% block page_checkout_confirm_form_submit %}
                {# @deprecated tag:v6.5.0 - Bootstrap v5 removes `btn-block` class, use `d-grid` wrapper instead #}
                {% if feature('v6.5.0.0') %}
                    <div class="d-grid">
                        <button id="confirmFormSubmit"
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                                form="confirmOrderForm"
                            {% if page.cart.errors.blockOrder %}
                                disabled
                            {% endif %}
                                type="submit">
                            {{ "checkout.confirmSubmit"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <button id="confirmFormSubmit"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"
                            form="confirmOrderForm"
                        {% if page.cart.errors.blockOrder %}
                            disabled
                        {% endif %}
                            type="submit">
                        {{ "checkout.confirmSubmit"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                    </button>
                {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block base_footer %}
    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/footer/footer-minimal.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is that twig file you shared from your extension? I'm confused, because it touches so many blocks and even looks like it contains duplicate code.

Comment: The template seems to be correct (although it could probably be optimized, as per LastSgt suggestion).
To be honest it looks like a browser-rendering issue, I was able to reproduce the same issue with the original checkout template.